# Set Craft variables in the markup

Tags: templating, variable

I am trying to use Twig methods/loops while working on a design/template. To avoid touching the CP or the DB i did set variables directly in the template, like :

```
{% set service = 
  { 
    'titel': 
      [
        'Titel1', 
        'Titel2'
      ],
  }
%}

{% for i in 0..1 %}
  <p>{{ service.headerQuote }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It would be much better to be able to use the standard Craft methods, so if I move from templating/designing towards the DB i wouldn't have to touch the methods in my markup.  Unfortunately, I can't make it work... I tried:

```
{% set service = { titel: 
                   [ 
                     'hallo',
                     'hallo2' 
                    ]
                  } 
                %}

{% for entry in craft.entries
      .section('service') %}

      <p>{{ entry.titel }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

I tried to set the service entry to craft.entries.section('service') but that doesn't work as well... what am I missing?

Is it even possible to overwrite Craft variables in the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a variable that has the same keys as the entry model will have.

```
{% set entries = [{title: 'hello', ...}, {title: 'hello2', ...}] %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {# stuff #}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, when you want to move to using the database, just switch what  `entries` is set to:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('service') %}
```

That way the template will still look exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I'm following what you're going for, if you want to access the array values of the `titel` property in the `service` variable, you'd do so like:

`service.title[0]`, which would equal `hallo` and `service.title[1]`, which would equal `hallo2`.

So would look like:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section(service.title[0]) %}

  <p>{{ entry.titel }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks a lot brad, i think my question was a bit confusing.